# How to get the row and col of a particular element in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencv

I am trying to get the row and col of a particular element from a CvMat which is a 3-channel matrix.

Is there any function in OpenCV with which I can get this? Something like Matlab's 'find' function, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

If that "particular element" is a color pixel and it is unique, you can mask it using

`inRange(src,your_color,your_color,mask)`

then use `minMaxLoc()` to get the index of that unique point you are looking for.

Of course this is only worth it if you are **not** after a single pixel (get the single pixel rather with a simple loop), but if you don't do too many of this it could be easier to do this overkill, as it is short, afterall.

If you are looking for a submatrix, use `matchTemplate` then `minMaxLoc` to get the index.

Answer (score 0):

if you use cpp,it's OK to write like this:

> Mat readmat = imread("pic", 0);
>   cols = readmat.cols;
>   rows = readmat.rows;

BTW,you can refer [here](http://opencv.itseez.com)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually I want to get row and cols of a particular element in the CvMat not the size of CvMat.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard about such function in Opencv. still you can scan your matrix looking for the value you need to find. I think also "find" function works in a similar way.

Comment: please if you think my answer is good can you check it as the correct answer?